# AngularJS. How to add watch to a global properties?

Tags: angularjs

Hi I developp a directives where I put 2 watch like this :

```
$scope.$watch('master.origin', updateMap);
$scope.$watch('master.destination', updateMap);
```

The proble is that sometime i set "master" by var copy like this :

```
$scope.master= angular.copy($scope.dirRequest);
```

and on this case i have updatemap trigger twice.

How to add a watch to master ?

```
   $scope.$watch('master', updateMap);  // This doesn't work
```

How to avoid that uploadmap be trigger twice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$watch` works on object reference by default (e.g it only triggers if the watched object is a different one than the cached reference) - if you want to check for object equality instead you have to add a third parameter:

```
$scope.$watch('master', updateMap, true);
```